# change wordpress gallery shortcode to slider

Tags: shortcode, gallery, slideshow, images

Hi I wanted to change the default WordPress gallery short-code and make it a slider.

```
   remove_shortcode( 'gallery' );
function gallery_filter( $atts, $content = null ) {

  extract(shortcode_atts(array('gallery_name' => ''), $args));
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => 3,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image'

        );
        $output .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="'. get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) .'/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="'. get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) .'/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="'. get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) .'/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="'. get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) .'/js/bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="'. get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) .'/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
';
        $output .= '
        <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(window).load(function() {
         jQuery(".gallery-slider").bjqs({

width : 639,
height : 300,
animtype : "slide", 
animduration : 450, 
animspeed : 4000, 
automatic : false,
showcontrols : true, 
centercontrols : false, 
nexttext : "Next", 
prevtext : "Prev",
showmarkers : false, 
centermarkers : false, 
keyboardnav : true, 
hoverpause : true, 
usecaptions : true, 
randomstart : true, 
responsive : true 
});
     });
</script>';

$output .= "<div class='gallery-slider' style='margin-bottom:10px;'><ul class='bjqs'>";

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );

    if ( $attachments )
    {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment )
        {                   
             $output .= "<li>";
            $output .= "<a rel='example_group' href='".wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID )."' title='". get_the_title()."'>";
            $output .= "<img width='639px' height='300px' src='".wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID )."' />";
            $output .= "</a>";
             $output .= "</li>";    


              }
             $output .= " </ul></div>";
  }
  return $output;

  }
add_shortcode( 'gallery' , 'gallery_filter' );
```

Comment: Which `foreach`? I don't recognize `gallery_first_image`. Where did that come from from? Based on the way you are using it I'd expect it to return a string... just a guess though.

Comment: for each gallery image it outputs the following. I know I am using it wrong thought.

Comment: No. You use `foreach` several times. Which time triggers the error? Do you know? If so, please narrow the problem down.

Comment: That is probably a new question. It would be nice of you to answer your own question and show the solution, for the sake of anyone else with a similar problem.

Comment: the li causes this error, if you remove the li it shows 3 images and function works perfectly, with li this works but it repeats the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code removes the wordpress native gallery in which shows thumbnails and calls the permalink to attachment.php where it shows the image by itself.

the following code makes it a slider using a easy slider with limited animation and transition effects.

**1. Calls the arguments for the transition effect and call the js**

```
            $output .= '
            <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(window).load(function() {
             jQuery(".gallery-slider").bjqs({

    width : 639,
    height : 300,
    animtype : "slide", 
    animduration : 450, 
    animspeed : 4000, 
    automatic : false,
    showcontrols : true, 
    centercontrols : false, 
    nexttext : "Next", 
    prevtext : "Prev",
    showmarkers : false, 
    centermarkers : false, 
    keyboardnav : true, 
    hoverpause : true, 
    usecaptions : true, 
    randomstart : true, 
    responsive : true 
    });
         });
    </script>';
```

**2. Output the slider effect.**

```
$output .= "<div class='gallery-slider' style='margin-bottom:10px;'><ul class='bjqs'>";

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );

    if ( $attachments )
    {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment )
        {                   
             $output .= "<li>";
             $output .= "<img src='".wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID )."' />";
             $output .= "</li>";    
        }
             $output .= " </ul>";
  }
  return $output;

  }
```

below you put it all together. with the js and the arguments to set the transition effects.

```
remove_shortcode( 'gallery' );
    function gallery_filter( $atts, $content = null ) {

  extract(shortcode_atts(array('gallery_name' => ''), $args));
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => 3,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image'

        );
        $output .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="'. get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) .'/js/bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>';
        $output .= '
        <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(window).load(function() {
         jQuery(".gallery-slider").bjqs({

width : 639,
height : 300,
animtype : "slide", 
animduration : 450, 
animspeed : 4000, 
automatic : false,
showcontrols : true, 
centercontrols : false, 
nexttext : "Next", 
prevtext : "Prev",
showmarkers : false, 
centermarkers : false, 
keyboardnav : true, 
hoverpause : true, 
usecaptions : true, 
randomstart : true, 
responsive : true 
});
     });
</script>';

$output .= "<div class='gallery-slider' style='margin-bottom:10px;'><ul class='bjqs'>";

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );

    if ( $attachments )
    {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment )
        {                   
             $output .= "<li>";
             $output .= "<img src='".wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID )."' />";
             $output .= "</li>";    
        }
             $output .= " </ul>";
  }
  return $output;

  }
add_shortcode( 'gallery' , 'gallery_filter' );
```

now i am having an issue with it outputting 5 images instead of all 3 attachment images. Images are repeating twice. Any help would be appreciated and would update the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have above... I would change "numberposts" to "posts_per_page".
And then I would change the "get_posts" to  "new WP_Query"

```
    remove_shortcode( 'gallery' );
    function gallery_filter( $atts, $content = null ) {

  extract(shortcode_atts(array('gallery_name' => ''), $args));
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image'
        );

        $output .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="'. get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) .'/js/bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>';
        $output .= '
        <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(window).load(function() {
         jQuery(".gallery-slider").bjqs({

width : 639,
height : 300,
animtype : "slide", 
animduration : 450, 
animspeed : 4000, 
automatic : false,
showcontrols : true, 
centercontrols : false, 
nexttext : "Next", 
prevtext : "Prev",
showmarkers : false, 
centermarkers : false, 
keyboardnav : true, 
hoverpause : true, 
usecaptions : true, 
randomstart : true, 
responsive : true 
});
     });
</script>';

$output .= "<div class='gallery-slider' style='margin-bottom:10px;'><ul class='bjqs'>";

             $attachments = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($attachments->have_posts()) : $attachments->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;               
             $output .= "<li>";
             $output .= "<img src='".wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID )."' />";
             $output .= "</li>";    
             endwhile;
             $output .= " </ul>";
             endif;
  return $output;

  }
add_shortcode( 'gallery' , 'gallery_filter' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing and adding correctly but still pulling in the entire media library which is not that helpful. If you want to *just* pull in the ids that you've included in the corresponding gallery shortcode use the following example:

#### 1) Get ids from gallery shortcode

```
function grab_ids_from_gallery() {

global $post;
$attachment_ids = array();
$pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
$ids = array();

if (preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $post->post_content, $matches ) ) { 
$count=count($matches[3]);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $atts = shortcode_parse_atts( $matches[3][$i] );
    if ( isset( $atts['ids'] ) ){
    $attachment_ids = explode( ',', $atts['ids'] );
    $ids = array_merge($ids, $attachment_ids);
    }
}
}
  return $ids;

 }
add_action( 'wp', 'grab_ids_from_gallery' );
```

#### 2) Replace gallery with slider

```
remove_shortcode( 'gallery' );
    function gallery_filter( $atts, $content = null ) {

  extract(shortcode_atts(array('gallery_name' => ''), $args));
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image'

        );
        $output .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="'. get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) .'/js/bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>';
        $output .= '
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(window).load(function() {
            jQuery(".gallery-slider").bjqs({
                height : 550,
                animtype : "fade", 
                animduration : 450, 
                animspeed : 4000, 
                automatic : false,
                showcontrols : true, 
                centercontrols : true, 
                nexttext : "&#9654;", 
                prevtext : "&#9664;",
                showmarkers : true, 
                centermarkers : true, 
                keyboardnav : true, 
                hoverpause : true, 
                usecaptions : true, 
                randomstart : true, 
                responsive : true 
            });
       });
       </script>';

$output .= "<div class='gallery-slider' style='margin-bottom:10px;'><ul class='bjqs'>";

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
  $grabids = grab_ids_from_gallery();

    if ( $attachments )
    {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment )
        {     
            if ( in_array( $attachment->ID, $grabids ) ) {             
                 $output .= "<li>";
                 $output .= "<img src='".wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID )."' />";
                 $output .= "</li>";  
            }  
        }
             $output .= " </ul>";
  }
  return $output;

  }

  add_shortcode( 'gallery' , 'gallery_filter' );
```

By adding the function `grab_ids_from_gallery` we can then pulls those ids from the array. I found this to be the best solution for me after looking around for a bit.